# [Formarray][SubmitForm][Angular]Not able to submit value from formarray

Tags: angular, submit, formarray

I'm trying to submit value coming from a formarray. However it does not work... Here is the code

```
<form  *ngIf="incomeForm" [formGroup]="incomeForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm()">
  <table class="table table-border">
    <thead>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>somme</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <ng-container formArrayName="budgetIncomes" *ngFor="let item of incomesArray.controls; let i=index">

        <tr *ngIf="item.get('isEditable').value" [formGroupName]="i">

          <td><input type="text" ngModel  formControlName="label"></td>
          <td><input type="number" ngModel  formControlName="somme"
                     [ngStyle]="{'color': item.get('somme').value >=0? 'green' : 'red'}"></td>
          <button (click)="doneRow(item)">done</button>
        </tr>

        <tr *ngIf="!item.get('isEditable').value">
            <td>{{item.get('label').value}}</td>
            <td>{{item.get('somme').value}}</td>
            <button (click)="editRow(item)">edit</button>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="action-container">
    <button class="add" (click)="addIncome()">Add Income</button>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enregistrer</button>
</form>

<p class="result" [ngStyle]="{'color': getSum()>=0? 'green' : 'red'}">{{getSum()}}</p>
```

```
  onSubmitForm() {
  const formValue = this.incomeForm.value;
  const newBudget = new Budget(
formValue['label'],
formValue['somme']
 )
 this.budgetService.validateBudget(newBudget);

}
```

It does seems the value from newBudget are undefined but I don't understand why ?

Any idea ?

Thanx in advance ! :)

Comment: Can you show how you are building your form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form structure is something like this:

```
-- FormGroup: incomeForm
---- FormArray: budgetIncomes
------ FormGroup: 
-------- FormControl: label
-------- FormControl: somme
```

This means that the data structure of your form value will be like this:

```js
{
  incomeForm: {
    budgetIncomes: [
      { 
        label: string,
        somme: number
      },
      { 
        label: string,
        somme: number
      },
      // ... 
    ]
  }
}
```

So you will be able to get an array of `Budget` objects with the following code:

```js
onSubmitForm() {
  const formValue = this.incomeForm.value;
  const budgets = formValue.budgetIncomes.map(group => new Budget(
    group['label'],
    group['somme']
  ));

  // TODO: validate budgets...
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your  answer. It works and help me a lot to understand better how it works :)

Comment: I do have another problem . I'm not able to display the result correctly in my result budget hmtl and I don't understand why ^^; : https://stackblitz.com/github/LucNamur86/budget4

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but I always like to print out the top-level object if I want to see what the actual model is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-zwikzk

Comment: Thx. Well, I'm trying to understand how it works and how angulars works rihgt now haha. What I want is to display the value of my label and my somme in this result html part for a later use :) Thx a lot, it really helps me !